# What does "<service_name> dead but subsys locked" mean?

Tags: linux, centos, memcached, service

I'm trying to run memcached on a centos box and it runs for a while, but then ends up in this state:

**memcached dead but subsys locked**

netstat shows this:

```
tcp        0      0 :::11211                    :::*                        LISTEN      
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:11211               0.0.0.0:*
```

ps shows this:

```
nobody   21983  0.0  1.8  60272 19912 ?        Ssl  16:46   0:00 memcached -d -p 11211 -u nobody -c 1024 -m 64
```

Anyone know what that means?

Answer (score 65, accepted):

This means the service was running at one time, but has crashed.

When you start a service, it creates a "lock" file to indicate that the service is running.  This helps avoid multiple instances of the service.  When you stop a service, this lock file is removed.

When a running service crashes, the lock file exists but the process no longer exists.  Thus, the message.

Look at the two areas `/var/run/*.pid` and `/var/lock/subsys/*`.  These are expected to agree with each other.  That is, if the (emtpy file) lockfile `/var/lock/subsys/crond` exists, then the first line of the file `/var/run/crond.pid` is expected to contain the PID of the process running for this service.  If no such process is running, then something is wrong.  If a process is indeed running (as you see) but it is not *that* PID, then something is probably confused.

Comment: Isn't it still running if it's bound to a port and listed in ps?

Comment: I extended my answer.  Do "ls /var/lock/subsys/memcached" (I assume this file exists) and then "cat /var/run/memcached.pid" and look at the first line.  The first line is the PID you should expect to see for memcached.

Comment: Sorry, I figured out what was going on.  It was still running.  I launched it using "sudo /sbin/service memcached start", but looking back in my history, I got the status using "/sbin/service memcached service".  

PEBCAK.  All is well.  Thanks for your help.

Comment: Ah, and running the status not as root, you may not have had read access to /var/run/memcached.pid, thus, the command assumed the subsystem was dead because it couldn't locate the correct process.