# Cannot get nscd to run. DNS cache stale as a result

Tags: domain-name-system, centos5

I'm trying to troubleshoot an issue on a MediaTemple server (running CentOS5) where the DNS cache has grown stale - I think because nscd has crashed.  I've tried restarting nscd:

```
# service nscd restart
Stopping nscd:                                             [FAILED]
Starting nscd:                                             [  OK  ]
```

This makes sense since I believe nscd has crashed so it shouldn't already be running, but When I view the status of nscd:

```
# service nscd status
nscd dead but subsys locked
```

And `ps -A` returns no processes related to nscd (I assume because it's dead).  I've edited `/etc/nscd.conf` and uncommented the line that defines the location for the log file.  It created the file but it never writes anything to it.

I tried looking at the init script but found that it's no help since the script thinks everything is running fine - the service returns that it started up correctly.

How do I 'unlock' the subsys that nscd is complaining about?

Comment: Duplicates ["What does '<service_name> dead but subsys locked' mean?"](http://serverfault.com/questions/26276/).

Comment: Side note - this should not result in a stale cache. While the cache state is maintained by nscd, NSS obtains the information by polling the daemon and not by reading a state off of the disk. If nscd is not running or able to service requests from NSS, then there is effectively no cache.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately these are bugs in the nscd init scripts and thhe status has no meaning. The init script is expecting the pid file to be `/var/run/nscd.pid` (which it would be if the init script was writing the pid file). Alas, `nscd` itself writes its pid file to `/var/run/nscd/nscd.pid`.

To simplify, try troubleshooting with `nscd` off.

If you want to know what `ncsd` is failing to start examine the output of `strace -f /usr/sbin/nscd`.

Comment: Can I ask what you mean by troubleshooting with `nscd` off? As far as I can tell, it's already not running.

Comment: Have you ruled out other name resolution problems? That is what I meant.

Comment: I'm able to ping a new host from the server (just tried serverfault.com) and the DNS lookup works fine so I don't think that's the issue. What else could I look for with regards to name resolution issues?

Answer (score 0):

Explore the option of the package bind-chroot (and its dependencies).  Simply yum install and modify your /etc/resolv.conf to point at 127.0.0.1.  It is bit more robust than nscd out of the gates.

Comment: This only caches dns.  It will not cache uid/gid.  They would need to verify why they are using nscd.  sssd is another option to replace nscd, but not trivial to configure.

Answer (score 0):

Nscd writes it's cache files to disk. I've seen problems with it before where it crashes starting if there's a problem reading this cache. Try deleting any files in the cache directory (should be /var/cache/nscd) and restarting nscd again.

Comment: That directory doesn't exist on the server.  I tried creating it and chown'd it to the nscd user but still no luck starting the service.

Comment: Try /var/db/nscd

Comment: Ah, that's where the files are.  I moved all the files out of the dir and tried starting it - it generated new files (group, passwd, and hosts) but still failed to start.

Comment: Rather than using the init script, try running nscd in debug mode ('nscd -d') and see if that produces any useful error messages

Answer (score 0):

I had a slightly different issue - I think it arose from running out of disk space on the system partition.  I killed the service using `$ sudo kill <pid>`, then delete `nscd.pid`, then start the service.  file location may differ based on OS and flavor.  For CentOS (and presumably other Redhat variants), `/var/run/nscd/nscd.pid`

Startup:

`$ sudo service nscd start`